# Is this a translation question?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/503654/whats-the-meaning-of-theres-no-stinkin-way-in-this-paragraph) about the phrase *no stinkin' way* has the [translation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag.

Here is the tag description for translation:

> Determining English equivalents for words or phrases in other languages (that is, translation into English). We don't actually do translations: we can try and help you with your own translation. Please see the detailed tag info for guidance on what to ask.

I'm not sure that it is a translation - I would consider the [idiom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom) or [idiom-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-meaning) tags more appropriate. Am I right?

Comment: The translation   tag is  just a mistake. The OP is asking for its  meaning not for its translation.

Comment: @user240918 I'm glad you agree. I wanted to get some consensus on what is the most appropriate tag.

Comment: You've got the rep, just fix it next time you see it.

Comment: You could have asked the OP (but it was almost sure that no foreign language was involved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been changed now.

> The translation tag is just a mistake. The OP is asking for its meaning not for its translation. – user240918

Comment: I will accept as soon as the time limit has expired.